# How to replace resourceConfigurations for languages for Kotlin DSL?

Tags: android, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Android doc for Groovy (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages)

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    resourceConfigurations += ["en", "en-rGB", "fr", "ja", "b+zh+Hans+MO", "b+zh+Hant+MO"]
  }
}
```

How to replace it after migration to Kotlin DSL (https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-kotlin-dsl)?

Answer (score 10):

With this:

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    resourceConfigurations += listOf("en", "en-rGB", "fr", "ja", "b+zh+Hans+MO", "b+zh+Hant+MO")
 }
}
```